# How do I perform a stealth, non-lethal takedown on an exosuit enemy?

Tags: deus-ex-mankind-divided

When I try to do a non-lethal takedown the normal way (sneaking up behind the enemy and pressing the takedown button) against an enemy in an exosuit, the attack just bounces off the exosuit, doing no damage and alerting the enemy to my presence. How do I do a non-lethal takedown of an enemy in an exosuit without breaking stealth?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To perform a non-lethal takedown of an enemy in an exosuit, you must stun the enemy first with an EMP weapon (e.g. gun with EMP ammo, stun gun, EMP grenade). After stunning the enemy, you can perform the takedown the way you do with other enemies -- by sneaking up behind them an pressing the takedown button.

If the weapon you use to stun the enemy is silenced, or if you're far enough from other enemies that they will not hear the weapon, your stealth should be maintained.

Comment: Are you sure that the stun gun works on exosuits?  It does not affect any other systems that EMP ammo/grenades affect (cameras, turrets, lasers, alarm panels, *&c*).

Comment: Good point. I'm not sure -- I read it on a steam forum somewhere. I am sure of the other ones, so I'll remove the stun gun from the list until I find proof otherwise.

Comment: I tested stunning the Exosuit with the Stun Gun. This does work!

Comment: @Nijin22 Awesome, thanks for the update! I'll add the bit about the stun gun back into this answer.

Comment: I can also confirm that the stun gun works on exosuits.